# How to use local registered variable in shell command

Tags: ansible

I have the following ansible task which registered a variable:

```
- name: Get the existing access keys for the functional backup ID
  shell: "aws iam list-access-keys --user-name {{backup_functional_id}}"
  environment:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: '{{aws_access_key_id}}'
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: '{{aws_secret_access_key}}'
  register: existing_access_keys
```

I want some values from this registered variable to be used in a shell command.

I am able to log the value I need:

```
- name: Mark the old one as inactive for now
  debug:
    var: (existing_access_keys.stdout |from_json).AccessKeyMetadata[0].AccessKeyId
```

How do I access this in shell:

```
- name: Get list of available access keys to make sure new one is generated
  shell: "aws iam update-access-key --access-key-id (existing_access_keys.stdout |from_json).AccessKeyMetadata[0].AccessKeyId --status Inactive"
  environment:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: '{{aws_access_key_id}}'
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: '{{aws_secret_access_key}}'
```

I get:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "aws iam update-access-key --access-key-id (existing_access_keys.stdout |from_json).AccessKeyMetadata[0].AccessKeyId --status Inactive", "delta": "0:00:00.003190", "end": "2019-03-28 12:53:42.283188", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 2, "start": "2019-03-28 12:53:42.279998", "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: \"(\" unexpected", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: \"(\" unexpected"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

I tried using `{{ }}` which did not work as well.

I tried debugging using simple debug:

```
- name: Set old_api_key
  set_fact:
    old_api_key: {{ (existing_access_keys.stdout |from_json).AccessKeyMetadata[0].AccessKeyId }}

- name: Print old_api_key
  debug:
    var: old_api_key
```

But I got an error new `[`. tried escpaing it using `\` but that did not work either.

The offending line appears to be:

```
      set_fact:
        old_api_key: {{ (existing_access_keys.stdout |from_json).AccessKeyMetadata[0].AccessKeyId }}
                                                                                  ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose the variable expression in {{ }}.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ansible-playbook
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - vars:
      my_text: "World"
    shell: "echo 'Hello {{ my_text }}'"

$ ./playbook.yml -v
PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [shell] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "echo 'Hello World'", "delta": "0:00:00.002978", "end": "2019-03-28 15:06:58.623747", "rc": 0, "start": "2019-03-28 15:06:58.620769", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "Hello World", "stdout_lines": ["Hello World"]}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

In your case:

```
- name: Get list of available access keys to make sure new one is generated
  environment:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "{{ aws_access_key_id }}"
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "{{ aws_secret_access_key }}"
  shell: "aws iam update-access-key 
          --access-key-id {{ (existing_access_keys.stdout | from_json).AccessKeyMetadata[0].AccessKeyId }} 
          --status Inactive"
```

Comment: Yes when I pass the variable this ways it works. My variable is registered as you can see and as you can see there some manipulation too. I tried registering again using `set_fact` ( `({{existing_access_keys.stdout}} |from_json).AccessKeyMetadata[0].AccessKeyId` ) but that did not work.

Comment: You need to surround the entire expression, not just one part. I updated the main post for clarity.

Comment: Adding more testing results.

Comment: All template expressions must be surrounded by quotes - old_api_key: "{{ (existing_access_keys.stdout | from_json).AccessKeyMetadata[0].AccessKeyId }}"